# Is 17 really "slightly stronger" than 18?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Z , 17 referred to himself as the strongest fighter (before he knew the power of 16, Cell, etc). I don't remember where, but I'm positive that it was mentioned he was slightly stronger than 18. Now with the events of Dragon Ball Super and the Goku vs 17 sparring, is this still a valid assertion or has it been retconned?

Comment: I haven't watched the universal tournament arc yet so I'm quite behind. But is the 17 you speak of and classic 17 from the same world? I mean they could two different ppl

Comment: What do you mean from the same world? it's the same android, if that is what you mean

Comment: Like in the goku black arc. We know that each universe has it's own supreme kai and god of destruction. It is also possible that each universe has it's own version of 17. What I'm asking is if 17 is from the same world Goku and Vegeta are in(aka the one built by Gero) or some other place where he could have been built by someone else?

Comment: No, it's 17 from the same universe and timeline. The one you refer to as classic 17

Comment: But in Dende's words he is quite stronger now, and in the fight with Goku it seems to show that, even though we dont know how much Goku was holding back

Comment: Stronger than Piccolo for sure. They were almost matched in Dragon Ball Z

Comment: what? What is this GT? Well I'm going to leave this thread as a fav. I don't have an answer but my curiousity has been tickled.

Comment: I dont think he is as strong as in GT, though it was mentioned he also was holding back

Comment: I just remembered something from the episode, for something that's been said I think the lower bound of his possible power is in the level of SSJ2.

Comment: @kaz they are not talking about the (non canon) dragonbal GT but instead the (canon) dragonball super. which is the current dragonball anime.

Comment: @Thomas I'm aware of that. I just find it funny that with the loads of new content that they've created in super (gods, multiverse, more time travel, etc) that of all the things they choose to move into next they re-hash some conflict with android 17. Which was also done in GT, and according to what pablo said. It's not multi-verse 17, it's not a new 17, its the 17 that got eaten by cell and is somehow back again. Just like in GT. It's funny that they chose to make that actual cannon is all.

Comment: @kaz what is more funny is that they are androids....thus they shouldn't be able to improve their powers at all (just having endless ki)^^

Comment: @thomas because of that, I'm not sure it's considered these androids dont have ki anymore. I think it's being retconed. I believe it was mentioned early in Dragon Ball Z when fighting Piccolo these androids didnt have ki. But in the end of the Buu saga 17 gives his energy to Goku for the Genki Dama. isnt that ki? And now he has an aura when he fights. Plus it's mentioned they are modified humans who can increase their powers by doing exercises. If you have a theory with some basis you can answer this question I opened https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/does-17-has-ki

Comment: Some fans are arguing because he fights against Goku super saiyan blue that now he has god ki level power. I'm not so sure about that. Krilin also fought against Goku super saiyan blue and we know and it's left clear he isnt in the level of Goku SSB. Besides it's mentioned by 17 that Goku was holding back (also Goku states 17 was holding back). Impressive though that even if Goku was holding back, 17 doesnt show signs of efforts when fighting

Comment: @pablo the "no efforts" part would be consistent with them having unlimited energy (the 2 androids)

Comment: @Thomas I guess so, but he didnt look the same when fighting Piccolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, during the android saga, 16 was stronger than 17 who happened to be stronger than 18. Although the power difference between the 3 is certainly not a lot.

When Goku goes to recruit Android 17 to enter the tournament of power, it was stated by 17 that he spent that time gap training and had gotten a lot stronger. It's easily been over a decade or maybe even 2 since the cell games and while Android 18 hasn't really pushed herself and trained as much, 17 has spent his time training. We see 17 being able to fight SSJ2 Goku very easily and he also seemed to fair pretty well against SSJB Goku(Suppressed) very well. We know when Goku is not going all out because once he's forced to go all out, he immediately uses Kaioken just like he did with Toppo, Jiren, Hit etc. It was also stated by Goku that even Android 17 was holding back. So at the moment, Android 17 is high up on the ladder and very likely the fourth strongest fighter in Universe 7. Android 18, on the other hand, has received a relative power boost which all the characters, in general, have received to make them relevant in the tournament of power.

We see Piccolo easily defeat SSJ2 Gohan. Android 18 is very likely on the same level as Piccolo or maybe slightly stronger or weaker. Android 17 on the other hand is definitely stronger than SSJG Goku but not stronger than SSJB Goku.

Answer (score 1):

17 and 18 have all the same abilities and unlimited energy, but I feel like 17 is probably a lot stronger, because apparently 17 continued training and seems to be close to Goku's level, while 18 became a mother and didn't really continue her training. I may be wrong, but as far as I can tell, this seems to be the case.

Comment: your answer seems speculative

Comment: 17 took up the job of protecting the rare wild. How's that training?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken. I thought as they sparred, Goku stated that 17 must've trained hard, and 17 confirmed it. I guess he doesn't say he was training outright. But he did say he wasn't sitting around do nothing this entire time. So I think it's safe to assume that 17 trained plenty.

Answer (score -1):

Android 17 is stronger than 18 because ever since he returned for Dragon Ball Super, he has shown everyone how strong he has become. Even his Barrier improve since we last saw it in Dragon Ball Z. Because in the tournament he used his Barrier in different ways like using it as a Barrier punch on Aniraza and making his Barrier spinning around to toss over that cat girl. It’s amazing how strong he has become, and to me he’s the 3rd strongest character in Universe 7. Since 17 would definitely beat Freiza in a fight.